# How to dynamically update a Google Gauge

Tags: jquery, html, google-gauges

I have been trying to dynamically update a Google Gauge but despite looking at several other questions I cannot get it to work.

The code is below but what I need to able to do is set the slider to a value and then press the go link. This should update the gauge. All I can get to work is the change of the text.

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
            google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['gauge']});
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    </script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function recordValue() {

            var val = document.getElementById("amount").value;

            setValue(val);

            return true;

        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id='chart_div'></div>
    <p>
        <label for="amount">Slider value:</label>
        <input type="text" id="amount" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />
    </p>
    <div id="slider-range-max"></div>
    <div class="go"><a href="#" class="button" onClick="javascript:return recordValue();">Go</a></div>

  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
      range: "max",
      min: 1,
      max: 100,
      value: 50,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
  });
  </script>

<script type="text/javascript">

google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['gauge']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

var data;
var chart;
var options;

function drawChart() {
    data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Gauge');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
    data.addRows([

        ['Value', 20]

    ]);

    options= {
            animation: {
                duration: 2000
            },
            height: 300,
            width: 300,
            greenFrom: 40,
            greenTo: 100,
            yellowFrom: 20,
            yellowTo: 40,
            redFrom: 0,
            redTo: 20,
            max: 100
        };

    // make a temporary view to draw the chart in a blank state
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, {
        // create a calculated column that contains all zero's
        type: 'number',
        calc: function () {
            return 0;
        }
    }]);

    chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'Gauge',
        containerId: 'chart_div',
        dataTable: view,
        options: {
            animation: {
                duration: 2000
            },
            height: 300,
            width: 300,
            greenFrom: 40,
            greenTo: 100,
            yellowFrom: 20,
            yellowTo: 40,
            redFrom: 0,
            redTo: 20,
            max: 100
            }    });

    var runOnce = google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
        google.visualization.events.removeListener(runOnce);
        // use the real data to redraw
        chart.setDataTable(data);

        chart.draw();
    });

    chart.draw();
}

function setValue(val){
   data.setValue(0, 0, "['Value', val]");
   chart.draw(data, options);   
}

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you able to setup a JSFiddle for this example?

Comment: Having tried it seems the answer is no I can't - neither the gauge or the slider appear.

Comment: Please note you have also duplicated your load and setOnLoadCallback calls, at least one of which occurs before the callback is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got multiple errors debugging this page in Visual Studio 2012 but did solve the first problem (after ripping out the slider which will not fire up for some reason).

Basically you are updating column 0 with a string which is used for the gauge display.

You need to update column 1, with a numeric value:

```
function setValue(val){
    data.setValue(0, 1, parseInt(val));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

*If you are also after a fix for the slider too, please have another go first with this fix.*

Comment: Hi, thanks for that it has sorted the problem! However, the slider works fine for me. Can you tell me what browser you are using so I can test it there?

Comment: For Visual Studio 2012 testing I use IE 10 as it will simply break on errors. For JSFiddle testing I use Chrome with the F12 debug window open. I can get everything except the google gauge working in a JSfiddle... weird. JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/TxUkr/

Comment: @williamsdb: Worth asking that as a separate question: "Why doesn't the Google gauge appear in this JSFiddle?" :)